# Jupyter terminal problem: All output of command will exceeds the boundary of console window

Tags: linux, jupyter, suse, jupyter-console

I am using Jupyter terminal on SUSE Linux 12.3 and I get the problem showing in the following image.

[jupyter terminal problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwPbT.png)

It seems like a font problem because my command is still limited in the window.
I tried setfont but nothing changes.
Does anyone know how to fix this?